# CSS: Does backdrop-filter: blur have layer limitations?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a sidebar product filter [on this page](https://boyflix.com.br/shop/) activated by the white FILTRAR on top of the page (only for mobile).

I was able to apply a backdrop blur on the `.chosen.-drop` div correctly, blurring elements from the same sidebar, but when I try to apply it to `.mfp-content` and other divs in its hierarchy it doesn't blur the page behind the sidebar. Also, if I try to apply it to `.mfp-wrapper` I will get the whole page blurred.

BUT I'm also getting a "invalid property" warning when I try to apply a `-webkit-filter` to the same div, so I'm confused. Am I selecting the wrong div or is there a technical limitation to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: please add some code [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.